# REST API Custom Client in Call Options Header

Tags: rest-api, client-id

I'm trying to assign a custom name for the client element in [Call Options header](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_calloptions.htm).

**Sample code:**

```
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(auth_token),
    "Sforce-Call-Options": "client=SampleClient",
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
```

However, when I check the API Usage report, I don't see the sample client that I set. Instead, I see blank values for the client id.

Comment: Hi Michelle, do you have solved your problem ?
On my side, I have currently the same problem.